# How to specify column types in a google drive file?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I save a file in Google Drive (for documentation see [Google Drive Doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update))

```
File file = service.files().get("fileId").execute();

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("path/file.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", fileContent);

// Send the request to the API.
File updatedFile = service.files().update("fileId", file, mediaContent).execute();
```

The problem is that I have String values in my CSV file, that have numeric formats (for example 018), and when saving them in a Google Drive file, they are considered as numeric values (so I have 18 instead of 018).
 Is it possible to specify the column's type?

Comment: I am not sure there is anything you can do about that.   You can try and set Covert = true but that's going to covert your file to a google sheet I think which may or may not do the exact same thing.  The only thing I can think of would be to set quotes around your strings '018'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a single quote, ', at the start of every line. This informs Excel to not treat the value as a number.
Source: [how to write to csv with a leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502226/how-to-write-to-csv-with-a-leading-zero)